# Thinkpad L13 yoga virtualization doesn't work

Tags: linux, bios, virtualization, thinkpad, dualboot

I'm on my brand new Lenovo ThinkPad L13 with a i71165g7 CPU, with an endovourOS/win10 dualboot. This CPU is supposed to support virtualization as stated on the specification sheet. I tried to enable virtualization it as stated in [this](https://support.lenovo.com/lt/lt/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers) article, but it was already enabled and grayed out in a way it cannot be disabled.

However it clearly doesn't work, as the intel utility states that virtualization is not supported. Furthermore VirtualBox doesn't work correctly on Linux and BlueStacks throws the error -1101, which is typical for systems without virtualization support. How to troubleshoot this?

Images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As long as hardware virtualization is disabled in the firmware, any utility that determines if your processor supports it, will indicate support does not exist. Your second screenshot is unreadable, but it appears, VT-x is enabled but (again) the screenshot is unreadable so i am not entirely sure of that conclusion..  If it turned on, and grayed out so it cannot be disabled, but showing as unsupported by the utility that means you have software installed that requires it.  You cannot typically have multiple pieces of software that use VT-x installed at once.

Comment: @Ramhound: i apologize for the poor quality, the first screenshot only includes the labels for that purpose, it's in the same order in the second image

Comment: My conclusion is that VT-x and VT-d are both enabled without any way to disable them.  Do you have Hyper-V installed?

Comment: Weirdly enough the utility still says that virtualization is not supported, but it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Once again I will point out that it likely shows as unsupported due to a hypervisor being installed.  What hypervisors other than BlueStacks did you have installed?